# How to set margin of error for conditional all statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a conditional statement that checks whether certain values are all present in another vector, but I would like to modify the conditional such that there is a margin of error that satisfies some deviations from the conditional (I am trying to avoid floating points). Here is an example

```
x1= 2.595

x2= 4.231

x3=3.236

x= c(2.592,3.64,3.235, 5.33,4.229)

if(all(c(x1,x2,x3) %in% x)){print("pls help")}
```

Any ideas on how I could modify the above conditional statement to leave some leeway? So that `x1,x2,x3`
dont have to be exactly equal to any of the values in `x` for the conditional to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `threshold`, build an upper and lower limit and compare against those values.

```
threshold <- 0.05
lower_limit <- x - threshold
upper_limit <- x + threshold

all(sapply(c(x1, x2, x3), function(y) any(y >= lower_limit & y <= upper_limit)))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This looks promising. May I ask what ```sapply``` and  ```function(y)``` are doing in this particular case?

Comment: Also I assume ```y``` is just an arbitrary placeholder correct? nothing in particular about using ```y```

Comment: `sapply` iterates over each value `x1`, `x2` and `x3` one at a time, yes, `y` is just a placeholder to apply an anonymous function on the values coming from `sapply`.

Comment: Thank you. Last question: ```sapply``` iterates over each ```x1,x2,x3``` one at a time but it is still the case that all of those objects have to be present (within at least the margin of error) in ```x``` for the statement to be true correct?

Comment: Yes, because we have used `all` outside `sapply`. `all(sapply(c(x1......` so all of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` have to be in the range for the statement to be TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same tolerance approach, you can define a custom `%in%`-like function with the tolerance built in:

```
`%in_tol%` <- function(x, y, tol = .005) colSums(abs(sapply(x,`-`, y)) <= tol) > 0

y <- c(2.595, 4.231, 3.236)
x <- c(2.592, 3.64, 3.235, 5.33, 4.229)

y %in_tol% x
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Or with reduced tolerance:

```
`%in_tol%`(y, x, tol = .002)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```